# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UILabel!'

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm getting this error in XCode with Swift. I've tried a lot of other solutions I've seen on this site, but none seem to work.

```
    @IBAction func generateClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let int1 = Int(number1.text!)!
        let int2 = Int(number2.text!)!
        let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32((int2 - int1) + int1))
        numberText = "\(random)"
```

The goal is the pick a random number when they click the generate button. (Between the 2 numbers they specify, being number1 and number2)

Comment: Do you mean the random only can be `number1` or `number2` ？

Comment: I'm trying to change numberText to a random number between number1 and number2.

Comment: Can the random number be float number? or only can be int number?

Comment: I've only tried int. I changed a few things and now I have "ambiguous use of operation +".                                                                                                 
        let random =  arc4random_uniform(UInt32(int2 - int1) + int1)

Comment: Trivial as it is, accessing the labels text value can be one of those easy-to-miss issues for newbies.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose `numberText` is you UILabel reference.

You want assign to it's text Attribute like this:

```
numberText.text = "\(random)"
```